# How to add an object inside properites?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have a highcharts areagraph whose values are received from json whose format is as follows:

```
var Data = [{
      "Name": "A",
      "Categories": "03.01",
      "Locate": "1",
      "Value": 30
    }, {
      "Name": "A",
      "Categories": "03.02",
      "Locate": "1",
      "Value": 50
    }, {
      "Name": "A",
      "Categories": "03.03",
      "Locate": "1",
      "Value": 60
    }, {
      "Name": "A",
      "Categories": "03.04",
      "Locate": "1",
      "Value": 40
    }, {
      "Name": "A",
      "Categories": "03.05",
      "Locate": "1",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "B",
      "Categories": "03.01",
      "Locate": "2",
      "Value": 60
    }, {
      "Name": "B",
      "Categories": "03.02",
      "Locate": "2",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "B",
      "Categories": "03.03",
      "Locate": "2",
      "Value": 50
    }, {
      "Name": "B",
      "Categories": "03.04",
      "Locate": "2",
      "Value": 80
    }, {
      "Name": "B",
      "Categories": "03.05",
      "Locate": "2",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "B",
      "Categories": "03.06",
      "Locate": "2",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "C",
      "Categories": "03.01",
      "Locate": "3",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "C",
      "Categories": "03.02",
      "Locate": "3",
      "Value": 50
    }, {
      "Name": "C",
      "Categories": "03.03",
      "Locate": "3",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "C",
      "Categories": "03.04",
      "Locate": "3",
      "Value": 50
    }, {
      "Name": "C",
      "Categories": "03.05",
      "Locate": "3",
      "Value": 70
    }, {
      "Name": "C",
      "Categories": "03.06",
      "Locate": "3",
      "Value": 50
    }];
```

I want to add an object inside properties

```
var series = [], readyValues = {};



$.each(Data, function(index, value){
  if($.inArray(value.Name,Object.keys(readyValues)) == -1){
    readyValues[value.Name] = [];
  }
  readyValues[value.Name].push(value.Value);
});

$.map(readyValues, function(val, key){
  console.log(val+" "+key);
  var cat = {};
  cat.name = key;
  cat.data = readyValues[key];
  series.push(cat);
});

firstDate = {
            name: scope.jsondata.Name,
            data:  scope.jsondata.Vaule,
            color: '#f48d7f',
            type: 'area'
        }
```

I want to add  "firstDate" object inside name & data.

How to add an object inside properites?

Comment: You wan to add `firstDate` inside which name? I see one name in `firstDate.name` and one in `series[index].name` ? The same applies fot the `data`. And why do you want to put this there?

Comment: I want to add firstDate inside A data. And I try to retract the data with the same name of the B to generate that secondDate.

Comment: Honestly, I'm still confused :) Have you tried to push that firstDate to the series.data array? Like this: `series[0].data.push(firstDate)`.